# getting error "value '0' is not a valid value"

Tags: c#, syntax-error, unhandled

EDITED:

i am writing an autoclicker and its almost done but it has a weird problem...

in btnStart event i have written:

```
if (listViewPositions.Items.Count == 1)
{
    ClickIntervalStr1 = (listViewPositions.Items[(1) - 1].SubItems[(3) - 1].Text).ToString();
    ClickIntervalNum1 = Convert.ToInt32(ClickIntervalStr1);
    LeftOrRightClickStr1 = (listViewPositions.Items[(1) - 1].SubItems[(4) - 1].Text)
        .ToString();
    SingleOrDoubleClickStr1 = (listViewPositions.Items[(1) - 1].SubItems[(5) - 1].Text)
        .ToString();
}
```

and in timer (clickprocess) i have written:

```
timerClickProcessStopAfterXTimes.Interval = ClickIntervalNum1;
```

but when i press start button it gets this error: "Value '0' is not a valid value for interval. interval must be greater than 0."

i am sure everything is ok but why is this error shows up?!

here is the pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

please help...

FIXED:

i just had to write 4 lines of codes of `listViewPositions.Items.Count == 1` to `listViewPositions.Items.Count == 2` too and also others...

Comment: If a timer *would allow a value of 0* what would the tick be on? The timer raises an event depending on that value... `The value must be greater than zero, and less than or equal to MaxValue. The default is 100 milliseconds.`

Comment: Are you wanting to to be 0, or is the issue that it should be 100 but your int version is showing 0?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i know but look at the first picture... its when i click start button and the third picture is the action after start button codes in a timer

Comment: Why are you writing `Items[(1) - 1]` instead of `Items[0]`?

Comment: @JNevill yes.. as the picture 1 it is 100 and i want the program to set the interval to 100

Comment: @Rufus L i just wanted to not be confused! :|

Comment: Not sure why `(1) - 1` is less confusing than `0`...you've introduced unnecessary bracing and an extra operation to the code. Also, why are you calling `.ToString` on the `.Text` property, when it's already a `string`? The first line could be simplified to: `ClickIntervalStr1 = listViewPositions.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text;`

Comment: @Rufus L oh you are right xD i know im not pro yet sorry for that!

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the code shown in image #1? `listViewPositions.Items.Count` does not appear to be 1, considering the fact that the listview holds 3 lines in the screenshot (image #2). Use the debugger.

Comment: @Ruud Helderman holy.... i found out why its showing this error!!

Comment: @Ruud Helderman i had to write 4 lines of codes of `listViewPositions.Items.Count == 1` to `listViewPositions.Items.Count == 2` too and also others...

Comment: @Ruud Helderman you are the one who helped me fix this thank you very much!! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Value '0' is not a valid value for interval. interval must be greater than 0."

The obvious reason is because of `ClickIntervalNum1 = Convert.ToInt32(ClickIntervalStr1);`. The value of `ClickIntervalStr1` is evident of `0`...

Microsoft has this to say about the `Interval` property:

> The time, in milliseconds, between Elapsed events. The value must be greater than zero, and less than or equal to MaxValue. The default is 100 milliseconds.

To fix this, just make sure it's greater than `0`... (simple example):

```
 timerClickProcessStopAfterXTimes.Interval = ClickIntervalNum1 > 0 ? ClickIntervalNum1 : 100;
```

References:

[Timer.Interval Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=netframework-4.8#property-value) System.Timers

Comment: you are saying that `The value of ClickIntervalStr1 is evident of 0...` but look at the second picture its 100 and in first picture im getting that number and sent to clickintervalnum1

Comment: how is this possible!!

Comment: i had to write 4 lines of codes of `listViewPositions.Items.Count == 1` to `listViewPositions.Items.Count == 2` too and also others...